# Angularjs date pipe filter gives wrong output

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Currently I am using angularjs in my project in which i am converting a date format '2019-05-09T20:09:11.677Z' using angular js to 'MM/dd/yyyy' but its giving me wrong output '05/10/2019'. Expected Output is '05/09/2019'.

What is the issue? Can anybody help me.

{{'2019-05-09T20:09:11.677Z' | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}

Current Output (Wrong): 05/10/2019

Expected Output (Right) : 05/09/2019

Comment: This is happening because angularJS uses new Date() method to convert the text in date and this will move the dates to your timezone as I can see you are using the time as 8 pm add your timezone difference in it and you are getting that like if you are in india add 5 hours 30 mins as you are ahead +5:30 from GMT. To solve this just remove the time component from your date text.

Comment: @GauravSingh instead of removing the time component i can set the timezone {{ '2019-05-09T20:09:11.677Z' | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' : '+0000' }} like this it's fine na?

Comment: Yes this will work if you just have to show it in frontend. But if you will access in JS code you face the same issue again.

Answer (score 2):

Date filter considers your timezone. Since the date you're trying to print has 8pm as time, I guess you're in a timezone in the range +0400 and +1200, making the date falling into 05/10/2019.

If you want to force the timezone to something different, e.g. UTC, you can use

```
{{ '2019-05-09T20:09:11.677Z' | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' : '+0000' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify timezone as one of parameters.

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

eg:

```
{{date| date:'shortDate':'GMT' }}
```

For more Information [AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Small demo for your help [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-ceawgt)